# Close pygame window using keydown event and a flag doesnt work

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make it possible to close pygame window by pressing the "q" key. There are no errors but it does not work for some reason. Please help.

```py
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
pygame.init()
flag = True

class Ship:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = screen_rect.center
    def blitme(self):
        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)

def keydown(event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        flag = False 

ship = Ship()

while flag:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            flag = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            keydown(event)

    screen.fill((0,0,128))
    ship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Game loop is working while `flag = True`. Closing window works when I click on the window exit button, but pressing q does not have any results.

Comment: Perhaps a scoping issue in which it is not changing the `__main__` flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write to a variable in global namespace, within a function, then you have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to interpreted the variable as global:

```py
def keydown(event):
    global flag 
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        flag = False
```

If you do not declare the variable as global, a local variable (with the same name as the global variable) is generated in the local scope of ​​the function.